# How to explicity remove multiple cursors in VisualStudioCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I have multiple cursors, I can switch back to a single cursor with `esc` (`removeSecondaryCursors`). In the frequent case that I have exactly 2 cursors I would like to have the option to remove one of the cursors explicitly. As a general behaviour, say, `esc` would result in only remaining the topmost cursor, and `shift+esc` in leaving only the cursor farthest down the document. How could I achieve such behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a way to do exactly what you purpose (take top/bottom cursor), but you can remove specific cursors:

**Option 1**
`Ctrl + u` would undo the last cursor action (remove last added cursor)

**Option 2**
`Alt + Click` on the cursor you want to remove